# Hive query results to new table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a very simple query below, which counts the number of transactions that happen each hour on our platform.

The numbers are in the billions so the query takes some time.

As such, I'd like to be able to run the query hourly, appending the results to another table - so we can have less latency & less load on the cluster.

I have access to Hue to do this - I am using Hive. is the below the correct way to do this?

```
INSERT INTO table udsuser.healthcheck
SELECT dt, hour, count(*)as transactions, 'dpi_datasum' as feed, 'FULL' as environment
FROM dpi_datasum
WHERE hour=hour(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))-2
Group by dt, hour
```

Comment: If you want the query to run quicker, use Parquet backed tables  and Impala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    INSERT INTO table udsuser.healthcheck
    SELECT dt, hour, count(*)as transactions,'dpi_datasum' as feed,'FULL' as 
    environment
    FROM dpi_datasum
    WHERE hour=hour(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))-2
    Group by dt, hour
```

or

```
    INSERT overwrite table udsuser.healthcheck
    SELECT dt, hour, count(*)as transactions,'dpi_datasum' as feed,'FULL' as 
    environment
    FROM dpi_datasum
    WHERE hour=hour(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))-2
    Group by dt, hour
```